# DNS Configuration: Am I doin' it right?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, a-record

Here's how I have my DNS records setup:

```
domain.com          IN     A         <server ip>
sub1.domain.com     IN     CNAME     domain.com
sub2.domain.com     IN     CNAME     domain.com
www.domain.com      IN     CNAME     domain.com
```

sub1.domain.com and sub2.domain.com are alternate ways of accessing domain.com. By default my host had an A record for *.domain.com but I removed it.

Is this setup correct?

Comment: Is this configuration related to bind or a dns provider web interface (or any other software) ?
If this is a zone file in bind, you have some misconfiguration. The records should be:
"sub1  IN CNAME domain.com.".
Notice the lack of ".domain.com" in sub1 and the addition of "." in domain.com.

Comment: This is my configuration in my host's control panel interface.

Answer (score 2):

The `A` record for `domain.com` is exactly right, you can't use a `CNAME` there.

My personal view is that pointing a `CNAME` back at the apex of your domain is sub-optimal:

1. It inadvertently means that any other records at your apex (especially `NS`, `SOA` and `MX`) also exist for those subdomains.  That may have unintended consequences.
2. It's marginally slower than using an `A` record as the DNS client has to follow the CNAME chain.

To avoid the first problem my recommendation would be:

```
domain.com          IN     A         <server ip>
www.domain.com      IN     A         <server ip>
sub1.domain.com     IN     CNAME     www.domain.com
sub2.domain.com     IN     CNAME     www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you don't even need CNAME records, and I don't recommend using them unless you have a really good reason to do so.

```
domain.com          IN     A         <server ip>
www.domain.com      IN     A         <server ip>
sub1.domain.com     IN     A         <server ip>
sub2.domain.com     IN     A         <server ip>
```

Comment: Why do you not recommend using CNAMES?

Comment: They are faster (1 query vs 2 queries). It is especially useless when you are just looking at the same server, CNAMEs are best for pointing to a server outside your domain, see this article: http://www.rscott.org/dns/cname.html

Comment: After reading that CNAMEs are a bit slower, like you mentioned, I deleted my CNAMEs and replaced them with As. Now I can't access www.domain.com but can access domain.com. What should I do? OpenDNS's cache checker is returning NXDOMAIN for www. by the way

Comment: It may take some time for the changes to propagate. Some hosts can take 24-48 hours, some will have it updated in 4-6 hours.